# Front end entry form with Craft CMS

Tags: forms, twig

I am trying to create a form with Craft that allows users to rate entries in a specific section. The section that tracks the ratings has three fields: the ratings drop-down field, a user field, and an entry field. Here is my form right now:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ getCsrfInput() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="viewentry/{slug}">
  <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="userRatings">
  <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">

  <input type="text" id="user" name="ratings" value="{{currentUser}}" style="display:none;" readonly>

  <input type="text" id="restaurant" name="restaurant" value="{{entry.id}}" style="display:none;" readonly>

  <label for="ratings">Rate This Restaurant</label>
  <select id="ratings" name="ratings" required>
      {% for option in entry.ratings.options %}
        <option value="{{ option.value }}">{{option.label}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>

<input class="button" type="submit" value="Rate">
```

I have two text boxes that are recording the current user and the Entry ID of the entry I am trying to rate (we are on the _entry.html for this entry). Before I added the "display:none" they were both showing the correct information. Then I am pulling the options for the ratings field that I set in craft and setting them as the values for the drop down here (which is working).

When I try to submit I get a craft error: "Internal Server Error Trying to get property of non-object." Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the 'title' field ..

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="Free Registration Title">
```

It's a requirement